# Compare strings by SSE4 wrappers

Tags: c++, sse, sse4

I need to quickly compare two string on the machine with SSE4 support. How can I do it without writing assembler inserts?

Some wrappers like `long long bitmask = strcmp(char* a, char* b)` would be perfect.

Comment: it might depend on the compiler (including the version) and the flags used. If you use `gcc-4.7` did you try `-mcpu=native -O3` etc.?

Comment: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse42_comp.htm

Comment: Googling "sse4 strcmp" gives a lot of results with ready made assembler code. You can try to translate those to C using intrinsics. Have fun.

Comment: @Mysticial it's exactly that I need! Post it as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using inline assembly, you should use the Intel SSE intrinsics.

For string comparison, you'll need the SSE4.2 intrinsics:

Documentation is here:
http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-mac/GUID-6E9CFDF2-5DF6-42A4-B429-0E2CD441342E.htm

Comment: And you are correct. They changed the link. Updated with the new one.

Comment: Note that SSE4.2 instructions are generally *not* worth using for strcmp or strlen.  You can do better with SSE2 or especially AVX2, which is what glibc does in practice.  See links at the top of [my answer on Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57676035)  (That question is about glibc's fallback C implementation, which is never used on x86.)

Answer (score 2):

Use Agner Fog's asmlib.  http://www.agner.org/optimize/#asmlib

He's already taken the trouble for writing the code in assembly for you including using SSE4.2 instructions.  Use his function `A_strcmp` (or the case insensitive version `A_stricmp`).

It would be interesting so how a method using intrinsics compares in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article of using SSE 4.2 for boosting string operations:
http://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2