# `movaps` vs. `movups` in GCC: how does it decide?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, x86, memory-alignment

I recently researched a segfault in a piece of software compiled with GCC 8. The code looked as follows (this is just a sketch)

```
struct Point
{
  int64_t x, y;
};

struct Edge
{
  // some other fields
  // ...
  Point p; // <- at offset `0xC0`

  Edge(const Point &p) p(p) {}
};

Edge *create_edge(const Point &p)
{
  void *raw_memory = my_custom_allocator(sizeof(Edge));
  return new (raw_memory) Edge(p);
}
```

The key point here is that `my_custom_allocator()` returns pointers to unaligned memory. The code crashes because in order to copy the original point `p` into the field `Edge::p` of the new object the compiler used a `movdqu`/`movaps` pair in the [inlined] constructor code

```
movdqu 0x0(%rbp), %xmm1  ; read the original object at `rbp`
...
movaps %xmm1, 0xc0(%rbx) ; store it into the new `Edge` object at `rbx` - crash!
```

At first, everything seems to be clear here: the memory is not properly aligned, `movaps` crashes. My fault.

But is it?

Attempting to reproduce the problem on Godbolt I observe that GCC 8 actually attempts to handle it fairly intelligently. When it is sure that the memory is properly aligned it uses `movaps`, just like in my code. This

```
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>

struct P { unsigned long long x, y; };

unsigned char buffer[sizeof(P) * 100];

void *alloc()
{
  return buffer;
}

void foo(const P& s)
{
  void *raw = alloc();
  new (raw) P(s);
}
```

results in this

```
foo(P const&):
    movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsi]
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR buffer[rip], xmm0
    ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/a3uSid

But when it is not sure, it uses `movups`. E.g. if I "hide" the definition of the allocator in the above example, it will opt for `movups` in the same code

```
foo(P const&):
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rdi
    call    alloc()
    movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbx]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cNKe5A

So, if it is supposed to behave that way, why is it using `movaps` in the software I mentioned at the beginning of this post? In my case the implementation of `my_custom_allocator()` is not visible to the compiler at the point of the call, which is why I'd expect GCC to opt for `movups`.

What are the other factors that might be at play here? Is it a bug in GCC? How can I force GCC to use `movups`, preferably everywhere?

Comment: What is `alignof(Edge)` in the real code? If it is `16` or more, then it seems clear why the compiler can assume that `p` is 16 byte aligned, given its offset. Your `P` and `Point` only have 8 byte alignment, so that is not by itself safe for `movaps`.

Comment: You mean `void *raw_memory`, right?  You wrote `void raw_memory`.

Comment: Updated my answer with some more ideas that might or might not be relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: `alignof(Edge)` was 16 because of `long double` on x86-64 System V, so it's UB to have one at a less-aligned address.  This tells GCC it's safe to use `movaps`.

IDK why loading it from `(%rbp)` didn't also use `movaps`.  I thought that implied Edge wouldn't be 16-byte aligned, so there's a whole section of this answer based on that guess (which I moved to the end).

---

### Some types can require 16-byte alignment, notably `long double`

**`alignof(max_align_t) == 16` on x86-64 System V.**  A drop-in replacement for `malloc` needs to return memory at least that aligned, for allocations of 16 bytes or larger.

(Smaller allocations of course couldn't hold a 16-byte object and therefore can't require 16-byte alignment.  You can ask for a specific instance of an object to be over-aligned with `alignas(16) int foo;`, but if a type itself has higher alignment it also has larger `sizeof` so an array will still obey the normal rules as well as having every element satisfy the alignment requirement.)

See also [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64) where auto-vectorization with a misaligned `uint16_t*` leads to a segfault.  Also [Pascal Cuoq's blog about alignment](https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2020/04/06/gcc-always-assumes-aligned-pointers/) and having objects with less alignment than `alignof(T)` is undefined behaviour, and how assumption of no UB runs deep for compilers.

---

### Instruction selection

**GCC and clang use `movaps` whenever they can prove that memory must be sufficiently aligned.** (By assuming no UB).  On Core2 and earlier, and K10 and earlier, unaligned store instructions are slow even if the memory happens to be aligned at runtime.

Nehalem and Bulldozer changed that, but GCC still uses `movaps` even with `-mtune=haswell`, or even `vmovaps` with `-march=haswell` even though that can only execute on CPUs with cheap `vmovups`.

MSVC and ICC never use `movaps`, hurting perf on very old CPUs but letting you get away with misaligning data sometimes.  They will fold aligned loads into memory operands for SSE instructions like `paddd xmm0, [rdi]` (which requires alignment, unlike the AVX1 equivalent) so they will still make code that faults on misalignment *sometimes*, but usually only with optimization enabled.  IMO that's not particularly great.

---

`alignof(Point)` should only be 8 (inheriting the alignment of its most-aligned member, an `int64_t`).  So GCC can only prove 8-byte alignment for an arbitrary `Point`, not 16.

For static storage, GCC can know that it chose to align the array by 16 and thus can use `movaps` / `movdqa` to load from it.  (Also, the x86-64 System V ABI requires that static arrays of 16 bytes or larger be aligned by 16, so GCC can assume this even for an `extern unsigned char buffer[]` global defined in some other compilation unit.)

You haven't shown a definition for `Edge` so IDK why it has 16-byte alignment, but possibly `alignof(Edge) == 16`?  Otherwise yes, that might to be a compiler bug.

But the fact that it loads the original `Edge` object from the stack with `movups` would seem to indicate that `alignof(Edge) < 16`

---

Possibly `raw_memory = __builtin_assume_aligned(raw_memory, 8);` could help?  IDK if that can tell GCC to assume *lower* alignment than it already thought it could assume based on other factors.

---

You could tell GCC that `Edge` (or `int` for that matter) can always be under-aligned by defining a typedef like this:

```
typedef long __attribute__((aligned(1), may_alias)) unaligned_aliasing_long;
```

`may_alias` is actually orthogonal to alignment, but it's worth mentioning because one of the use-cases for this would be loads out of a `char[]` buffer for parsing a byte stream.  In that case you'd want both.  That's an alternative to using `memcpy(tmp, src, sizeof(tmp));` to do unaligned strict-aliasing-safe loads.

**GCC uses `may_alias` to define `__m128`, and `may_alias,aligned(1)` as part of defining `_mm_loadu_ps` (the intrinsic for unaligned SIMD loads like `movups`).**  (You don't need `may_alias` for loading a vector of float from a `float` array, but you do need `may_alias` for loading it from something else.)  See also [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond)

And see [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650895/why-does-glibcs-strlen-need-to-be-so-complicated-to-run-quickly/57676035#57676035) for scalar code that I think is safe for under-aligned / aliasing `unsigned long`, unlike glibc's fallback C implementation.  (Which has to be compiled without `-flto` so it can't inline into other glibc functions and break because of strict-aliasing violation.)

---

### Allocators and assumed alignment

(This section was written assuming that `alignof(Edge) < 16`.  This was not the case here, and the function attributes might be useful to know about even though they're not the cause of the problem.  And probably not a viable workaround either.)

You might be able to use `__attribute__ ((assume_aligned (8)))` on your allocator to tell GCC about the alignment of the pointer it returns.

GCC may possibly be assuming for some reason that your allocator returns memory usable for any object (and `alignof(max_align_t) == 16` on x86-64 System V because of `long double` and other things, and also on Windows x64).

If this is not the case, you may be able to tell it that.  This [`mmap` mis-alignment Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64), we can see that GCC does "know about" `malloc` and treat it specially.  But if your function doesn't have an ISO C or C++ defined name, or GNU C attributes, that would be surprising.  IDK, it's the best guess so far based on what you've shown, if it's not a compiler bug.  (That is possible.)

From [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-assume_005faligned-function-attribute):

> ```
> void* my_alloc1 (size_t) __attribute__((assume_aligned (16)));
> void* my_alloc2 (size_t) __attribute__((assume_aligned (32, 8)));
> ```
>
> declares that `my_alloc1` returns 16-byte aligned pointers and that
>   `my_alloc2` returns a pointer whose value modulo 32 is equal to 8.

I don't know why it would assume that a `void*` returned by a function and cast to another type would have any more alignment than the type of the object being constructed, though.   **We can that it uses `movups` to load an `Edge` from somewhere.  That would seem to indicate that `alignof(Edge) < 16`.**

Also relevant is [`__attribute__((alloc_size(1)))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-alloc_005fsize-function-attribute) to tell GCC that the first arg to the function is a size.  If your function takes an explicit alignment as an arg, use `alloc_align (position)` to indicate that, otherwise don't.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to `aligned` and `assume_aligned`. I'll look into these immediately.

Comment: @AnT: Added a couple links with more detail about `__attribute__((aligned(1)))`, e.g. that GCC uses that as part of defining intrinsics like `_mm_loadu_si128`.  So it works for telling GCC about an under-aligned object.

Comment: I don't mean to doubt your claim, but just curious to read more on this - can you redirect me to the right paragraph in the ABI that states this?

> Also, the x86-64 System V ABI requires that static arrays of 16 bytes or larger be aligned by 16

Comment: @KarthikNishanth: *An array uses the same alignment as its elements, except that a local or global array
variable of length at least 16 bytes or a C99 variable-length array variable always has
alignment of at least 16 bytes. [6]*.  (https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI).  That wording applies to automatic-storage local vars (on the stack), and local vars with `static` storage-class.  Also to global variables which always have static storage-class, like the OP's `unsigned char buffer[size];`.  Technically not to global-scope `static` variables, if those aren't considered "global".

Answer (score 3):

As is correctly stated by other participants in the already posted answers, the triggering factor is the alignment requirements of my data type. The specific culprit turned out to be a `long double` data field also present in my `struct`, which slipped my attention initially. This `long double` data field forced the alignment requirement of the entire struct to become 16.

Again, formally, there's no room for debate here: violating this alignment requirement leads to undefined behavior. End of story.

But practically (referring to the implementation-specific behavior of GCC), this does not appear to be as clear cut though. There still is a strange peculiarity in GCC's behavior here.

Above, in my original question you can see an example of a struct with an alignment requirement of 8 (assume it has no `long double` fields in it). With this data type GCC behaves as I already described above:

1. When alignment of the `raw_pointer` is obvious to the compiler and it is known to be 16 or greater, GCC generates `movaps` instructions.
2. When alignment of the `raw_pointer` is obvious to the compiler and it is known to be less than 16, GCC generates `movups` instructions.
3. When alignment of the `raw_pointer` is not obvious to the compiler, it generates `movups` instructions.

So, in this case GCC plays it safe, it behaves permissively/defensively. Even if data is not aligned, in practice the code will operate "as expected". (Maybe I'm missing something and it is possible to make it GPF with 8-aligned data a well, but for what it's worth, I haven't encountered it yet.)

But once we jump to 16-aligned struct (say, by adding a `long double` field), the GCC logic changes into the following:

1. When alignment of the `raw_pointer` is obvious to the compiler and it is known to be 16 or greater, GCC generates `movaps` instructions.
2. When alignment of the `raw_pointer` is obvious to the compiler and it is known to be less than 16, GCC generates `movups` instructions.
3. When alignment of the `raw_pointer` is not obvious to the compiler, it generates `movaps` instructions (yes, `movaps`!)

Note the third point: this little detail is what caused the GPF in the aforementioned project. Here's a small example of the same crash: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5cd2be91ebba41e . (BTW, Clang appears to be even more strict in this regard. 16-aligned data? Use `movaps`, even if the pointer is "obviously" unaligned.)

Looking at situations 1 and 2, it appears that with 16-aligned data GCC also kinda *intended* to behave permissively/defensively, just like it does with 8-aligned data. But for some reason for situation 3 it chooses to go with `movaps` instead of `movups`. Why the inconsistency with 8-aligned decision process?

Again, obviously, "the behavior is undefined, it is your fault". But the above inconsistency between decisions made for 8-aligned and 16-aligned data strike me as a little strange. If this is intentional, it would at least be useful to have an option to have GCC handle 16-aligned data in the same way as it handles 8-aligned data, i.e. use `movups` when things are not entirely transparent.

On the second thought, there's really no "inconsistency" here. The logic is solid: with 8-aligned data GCC cannot assume universal applicability of `movaps`, so it *has* to act defensively even if the data is perfectly 8-aligned. With 16-aligned data GCC can formally deduce applicability of `movaps` in all cases, so it *does not have* to act defensively.

---

As a quick workaround for those who can't or don't want to 16-align their structs for some reason (memory savings, legacy projects etc.): declaring `long double` fields as `packed` "kills" their alignment requirement. If by doing so you successfully reduce the alignment requirement of the struct to 8 or less, the good old permissive GCC behavior will return.

Comment: Ah yes, `long double` is padded to 16 bytes and aligned on x86-64 SysV, up from size 12 / align 4 in i386 SysV.  So it can never cache-line split and can be copied around efficiently with SSE perhaps? For modern x86 with cheap split loads / stores, the old sizeof = 12 probably makes more sense (especially since [80-bit x87 load & store to actually *use* the values are still slower than normal 32 or 64-bit x87 loads/stores.](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9760)). But the ABI design I think made some sense at the time.

Comment: point 3 for an `alignas(16)` object - *When alignment of the raw_pointer is not obvious to the compiler* - you can think of `new (raw_memory) Edge(p);` or `*(Edge*)raw_memory = ...` as *telling* the compiler that memory is at least that aligned.  Assumption of no UB allows compilers to infer pointer alignment (and non-NULL-ness) from how a pointer is used.  Related: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) gives an LLVM compiler dev's POV on how to think about this: compilers love to infer things.

Comment: point 2. is the interesting part of this answer to me; neat that GCC will use `movups` for an object with `alignof(T)=16` in cases where it already knows about alignment and doesn't have to try to infer it from how the pointer is used.  I didn't expect that unless you used `memcpy`, or `__attribute__((aligned(8)))` or less on the `long double` member or on the whole struct in a typedef.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I assumed that GCC's conditional use of `movups` is an attempt to accommodate all kinds of "unaligned" memory access, which is/was kinda common on x86 platform in situations when we need to pack data for memory saving purposes. I know that formally unaligned access leads to UB, but the behavior can be defined as an implementation-specific extension. But apparently GCC had no intention to provide such an extension. At least until I start to properly use those attributes you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, so much code happens-to-work with misaligned pointers on x86 that it's easy to come to the wrong conclusion about what compilers intend to support.  e.g. https://pzemtsov.github.io/2016/11/06/bug-story-alignment-on-x86.html and https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2020/04/06/gcc-always-assumes-aligned-pointers/ both felt the need to debunk that idea, so you're certainly not alone.  I cleaned up my answer to also make that point early.  And yes, using `movups` for known-misaligned memory looks like a happens-to-work thing, or maybe a low-effort way to make some UB code run as intended.

Comment: based username btw

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Edge` struct has an compiler determined alignment requirement, the compiler s is free to assume that all objects of that type are properly aligned.  If your custom allocator does not return a pointer to properly aligned memory, your use of an object at that address results in Undefined Behavior.