# Possible to write various-typed value to a memory address with a single pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, malloc

I'm playing around with memory as a sort of academic exercise and trying to write values to the memory much like I'd do in assembly, basically by giving it a size (1,2,4,8) and a value and a memory address, something like:

```
movb $7,   -1(%rbp)      size=1; value=7,   address=-1 (pretend rbp=0)
movw $777, -4(%rbp)      size=2; value=777, address=-4
```

With doing this sort of stuff in C, do I need to create multiple pointers with different sizes to do these sort of random-sized writes? For example, current I'm doing it like this:

```
char* play_mem_block(size_t bytes)
{
    char *mem_block = malloc(bytes);
    if (!mem_block) {
        perror("Looks like there was an error");
        return NULL;
    }

    // write a one-byte char value at address0
    *mem_block = 'a';

    // write a four-byte (int) value
    int *mem_block_for_int = (int*) mem_block;
    *(mem_block_for_int + 1) = 4444;

    /* *(mem_block+3) = 4444; */     <-- possible to do this directly?

    return mem_block;

}
```

Comment: Asm like that is how C structs work; casting to a struct type with the layout you want is one option.  Beware of strict-aliasing rules in C if you want to do overlapping accesses with different types; use `memcpy` or in GNU C `typedef uint32_t unaligned_aliasing_u32 __attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias));`

Comment: @PeterCordes I see, what if just something random-access like : `*(mem_block+77) = 1234;` is that possible to do directly in C?

Comment: `mem_block` has type `char*`, and `1234` doesn't fit in one char.  What access width were you hoping that to have?  `*(mem_block+77) = ...` would require the right hand side to implicitly convert to `char`.  You can of course cast the pointer type (but that would violate `alignfo(int)` if you meant `int`) or use memcpy.

Comment: If you're bashing around at a low level you need to be aware of the type of value you want to write and how it may need to be converted. If `1234` is supposed to be an `int32_t` then you need to store it as one, then write `sizeof(int)` to that address using `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
*(int *)(mem_block + 4) = 4444;    // only safe for aligned offsets
```

or

```
((int *)mem_block)[1] = 4444;
```

In order to write as `int` you need an expression of type `int` to write through, hence the cast.

Be careful about alignment, some systems have alignment requirements, trying to write an `int` at offset of `3` bytes may be undefined depending on platform. To do unaligned writes safely you would need to use the `memcpy` version.

Your original approach is fine and arguably easier to read , so don't be in a hurry to do something different for the sake of it.

Comment: -- the explicit cast looks nice, I think that's wha I was looking for, thanks! `*(int*)(mem_block+4) = 4444;`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an adaptation that is closer to your goal:

```c
char* play_mem_block(size_t bytes)
{
    char *mem_block = malloc(bytes);
    if (!mem_block) {
        perror("Looks like there was an error");
        return NULL;
    }

    // write a one-byte char value at address 0
    char a = 'a';
    memcpy(mem_block, a, sizeof(a));

    // write a four-byte (int) value
    int ffffour = 4444;
    memcpy(mem_block + 1, &ffffour, sizeof(ffffour));

    return mem_block;
}
```

In practice you'll want to create a "buffer" handler of some kind for allocation, and then helper methods like this:

```c
void* write_int32_t(void* b, int32_t n) {
  memcpy(b, &n, sizeof(n));

  return b + sizeof(n);
}
```

Where you can stamp out variants of that for every type you need to write out. You could also write an inverse `read_int32_t` method:

```c
void* read_int32_t(void* b, int32_t* n) {
  memcpy(n, b, sizeof(n));

  return b + sizeof(n);
}
```

Which is just as trivial.

Comment: Can you pick a var name other than `ffff`?  It looks like it's supposed to be a hex constant :/  But yes, exactly, wrapper functions for memcpy of different sizes solves the alignment and strict-aliasing problems, and will inline to single store instructions on ISAs (like x86-64) that allow unaligned stores.

Comment: @PeterCordes For you, `ffffour`.

Comment: uh, ok I'll take it :P

Answer (score 2):

Asm like that is how C structs work; casting to a `struct foo*` with the layout you want is one option.

Beware of strict-aliasing and alignment rules in C if you want to do overlapping accesses with different types.  **C is *not* portable assembly language**; you have to obey C's rules if you don't want a compiler to "break" your code at compile time.  (Or from another PoV, for your code not to mean what you want and not be already broken.)  e.g. [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64) shows that alignment-related segfaults are possible after compiler optimization even on an ISA like x86-64 where normal scalar unaligned loads/stores never fault.

Use `memcpy(ptr+3, &u32value, sizeof(u32value));` for an unaligned 4-byte store that you can safely reload with a different type.  (For a var type like `uint32_t u32value = 1234;` - uin32_t is [required](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) to be exactly 32 bits wide with no padding, if the system provides it.)

With a decent modern compiler targeting an ISA (like x86-64) where unaligned loads are cheap, that `memcpy` will fairly reliably inline and optimize to a single `mov` store with the right operand size.

`*(uint32_t)(ptr+3) = 1234` would *not* be safe, because `alignof(uint32_t)` is 4 on most C implementations (ones with 8-bit char).  Since malloc itself returns memory sufficiently aligned to store any type (up to `max_align_t`), `ptr+3` is definitely misaligned (except on weird systems with wide char where sizeof(uint32_t)=1, or where it chooses not to require alignment of wider types).

---

**Or in GNU C** we can use type attributes to tell the compiler about under-aligned versions of types, and/or give them the same alias-anything ability as `char*`.

(`__m128i` and other Intel vector intrinsic types use the `may_alias` attribute; that's how compilers make it safe to `_mm_load_ps( (float*)ptr_to_int )` and stuff like that.)

```
typedef uint32_t unaligned_aliasing_u32 __attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias));


char *ptr = malloc(1234);

*(unaligned_aliasing_u32)(ptr+3) = 5678;   // movl $5678, 3(%rax)
*(unaligned_aliasing_u32)(ptr+5) = 5678;   // movl $5678, 5(%rax) overlapping 
int tmp = ((const uint32_t*)ptr)[1];       // mov 4(%rax), %edx   aligned so I used plain uint32 for example.
```

See part of my answer on [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650895/why-does-glibcs-strlen-need-to-be-so-complicated-to-run-quickly/57676035#57676035) for another example of using a may_alias load to safely read a buffer as `long`s, unlike glibc's version which is only "safe" because it's compiled with known compilers and without the possibility of inlining into a caller that loads or stores the same memory with a different type.  (That one does need to be aligned so I omitted the `aligned(1)` attribute.)