# Assembly, accessing bytes in eax

Tags: assembly, x86

How can I adress a specific byte in `eax`. I know that I can access byte 0 and 1 via `ah` and `al` but how can I access byte 2 and 3?

Comment: There are no names for them. What sort of things would you want to do with those bytes?

Comment: You can ROL or [ROR](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror) EAX by 16 or 24 to move the specific byte into position of subregister `AL` (0..7).

Comment: Not sure exactly which aspect you were interested in, like the ISA design vs. what instructions to use to move data around, but both of those have been asked and answered multiple times; see the linked duplicates and other search results for `site:stackoverflow.com access upper bytes of eax`

Comment: I want to do some SIMD on bytes. I cannot use SSE or AVX. In this case I just want to check, if any of the bytes is zero.

Comment: Then why do you want to access them one at a time?  That wouldn't be SIMD/SWAR.  For that, see  https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord / [Check for zero byte in a register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72552147)  .  If you want to do fewer loads but still check scalar, `movzx eax, word [mem]` and check AL and AH.

Comment: Minimizing loads is not necessarily useful vs. `cmp [mem], al` or something, though, which is still just a single uop for the front-end that can macro-fuse with a `jne`.  (`cmp byte [rdi], 0` / `jnz` can't macro-fuse on Intel Skylake, though, only micro-fuse the load+cmp.  So it could be worth it to zero a register outside a loop.  [What is instruction fusion in contemporary x86 processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56413517))

Comment: If you can use MMX, that gives you an efficient way to check 8 bytes at once, more efficient than the bithack especially in 32-bit mode.  But probably you're limiting yourself to integer regs for a use-case like a kernel, or retrocomputing on CPUs without MMX either.  Apparently Sapphire Rapids (and maybe Alder Lake P-cores) have fast-short-rep cmpsb/scasb which I think reduces startup overhead for `repne scasb` if you want to use that for strlen, but it's probably still worse than a scalar bithack for non-short strings where the branch mispredict on leaving the loop is not a big deal.