# How to check if a register contains a zero byte without SIMD instructions

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86-64, simd, swar

Given a 64 Bit general purpose register (Not a xmm register) in x64 architecture, filled with one byte unsigned values. How can I check it for a zero value simultaneously without using SSE instructions?

Is there a way to do so in a parallel way, without iterating over the register in 4 bit steps?

I tried to compare it with certain 64-bit masks but it is not working.

Comment: What is a "8 bit float value"? 1 sign bit, 3 exp-bits, 4 significant? Do you only want to check for `+0.0` or either `+0` or `-0`?

Comment: Do you only want to check for existence of a zero, or do want to know the position(s)?

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord for the SWAR bithack used in non-SIMD `strlen` implementation.  If they're sign/magnitude floats so `-0.0` is possible, AND to clear the sign bits first.  It might still be faster to `movq xmm0, rax` / `pcmpeqb xmm0, xmm1` (with xmm1 being zeroed earlier) / `pmovmskb eax, xmm1`, unless you're in kernel code or something where you can't use XMM regs.

Comment: If you also want the position of the first zero byte, that's another point in favour of `pcmpeqb` / `pmovmskb`, since you can just `bsf` or `tzcnt`.  Glibc's portable C fallback for `strlen` (using a bithack) just compares each byte in sequence once it finds a chunk containing a zero byte, rather than `__builtin_ctz` or anything ([Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57650895) quotes the code)

Comment: Please define the representation format for your 8-bit floats, as I'm not aware of a standard for that.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: njuffa's answer on [Speed up strlen using SWAR in x86-64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76401479) shows that `bsf` or `tzcnt` can be used on the result of the bithack, so it's still usable if you do want the position.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could do something like that:

```cpp
// True if any of the 8 bytes in the integer is 0
bool anyZeroByte( uint64_t v )
{
    // Compute bitwise OR of 8 bits in each byte
    v |= ( v >> 4 ) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0Full;
    v |= ( v >> 2 ) & 0x0303030303030303ull;
    constexpr uint64_t lowMask = 0x0101010101010101ull;
    v |= ( v >> 1 ) & lowMask;
    // Isolate the lowest bit
    v &= lowMask;
    // Now these bits are 0 for zero bytes, 1 for non-zero;
    // Invert that bit
    v ^= lowMask;
    // Now these bits are 1 for zero bytes, 0 for non-zero
    // Compute the result
    return 0 != v;
}
```

However, SIMD gonna be way faster. SSE is an absolute requirement on x64 architecture, all AMD64 processors in the world are required to support SSE1 and SSE2. Here’s SSE2 version:

```cpp
bool anyZeroByteSse2( uint64_t v )
{
    __m128i vec = _mm_cvtsi64_si128( (int64_t)v );
    __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i eq = _mm_cmpeq_epi8( vec, zero );
    return 0 != ( _mm_movemask_epi8( eq ) & 0xFF );
}
```

That’s 6 instructions instead of 16: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/v6e5cvsc8).

Comment: Peter Cordes supplied a link to a four-instruction SWAR implementation: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord

Comment: @amonakov: It's six x86-64 instructions (including BMI1 `andn` which combines `~` and `and`, and a `setne` to materialize the boolean).  It also includes two `mov r64, imm64` to materialize the 64-bit constants.  Unless you use memory source operands for the constants, like `test rdi, [rel mask_80]`.  Then you could get it down to 5 (including a register-copy or a pure load into a new register, since x86 doesn't have `add dst, src, mem` and the 64-bit constant is too big for LEA to copy-and-add.)

Comment: But yeah, the no-false-positives bithack is probably about as cheap as SSE2, maybe lower latency but perhaps worse throughput depending on front-end cost of setting up the constants, as long as you don't care where the zero byte is if there is one.  The bitmap from `pmovmskb` can be used with `bsf` or `tzcnt`.

Comment: @PeterCordes plus, if the test is in a small loop, then constants can be set up just once prior to the loop

Comment: @amonakov: If the test is in a loop, you should probably be using SIMD even if that means `movq` / `movhps` to load two separate 8-byte chunks, if the data's coming from memory.  (Then `test al,al` or `test ah,ah` or `test eax, 0xff00` to test 8-bit halves of the 16-bit mask, if you care about which 8-byte chunk had a zero byte.)  Or maybe there are use-cases inside loops for the scalar bithack.  With constants loaded ahead of time, the `v - 0x0101...` can be done with LEA to copy-and-add, with `-0x0101...` in a register.

Comment: @amonakov: OP's followup question ([page fault error with SIMD strlen (using SWAR in integer registers, not SSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76394019)) did put this in a scalar loop, and made a point of avoiding XMM registers.  Maybe they're implementing `strlen` in kernel code; that would be a good use-case for this.