# page fault error with SIMD strlen (using SWAR in integer registers, not SSE)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, simd, strlen, page-fault

The asm function `strlen` receives the link to an string as a char - Array. To to so, the functions may use SIMD on general purpose register, but without using xmm register or SSE instructions.

The functions checks with [bit manipulation](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord) in 8 Byte steps, if the string contains the zero which marks the end. If it does, it checks byte per byte if it is zero.
It works but I get page fault exceptions, which I don't know how to solve since the functions iterates in single steps in the last loop at the end.

```
        ; rdi <- const *char
        ; rax <- counter + return value
        ; rbx <- current array
        ; rcx <- Bitmask
        ; rsi <- Arr for calculation
       
    
    strlen:
        PUSH rbx
        PUSH rbp
        MOV  rbp,rsp
        SUB rsp,8      ; calling convention
    
        XOR rax,rax
        MOV rcx,0x7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F
    
    while_parallel: ;checks if next 8 byte contains end - zero 
        MOV rbx,[rdi+rax]
        MOV rsi,rbx
    
        AND rsi,rcx
        ADD rsi,rcx
        OR  rsi,rbx
        OR  rsi,rcx
        NOT rsi
    
        CMP rsi, qword 0
        JNE while_single
        ADD rax,8
        JMP while_parallel
    
    while_single:  ;check if next byte is zero
        CMP [rdi+rax],byte 0
        JE  end
        INC rax
        JMP while_single
   end:
    ADD rsp,8
    POP rbp
    POP rbx

   RET
```

Note that I must not use any SSE instructions nor xmm register.

Comment: You read 8 bytes at a time, from a possibly unaligned address. That may very well cross into unmapped page. If the input is not known to be aligned, then you should do single byte reads until it is.

Comment: You could round down the address at the start and then ignore the "garbage bytes", it's more annoying to work out than just doing some byte-by-byte until the address is aligned

Comment: Techniques for handling unaligned addresses that might be within 7 bytes of an unmapped page are the same for SWAR as for `strlen` in general, whether you go a word at a time or unroll to 64-bytes at a time with multiple SIMD vectors.  See [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37800739) .  See also [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57650895) which quotes glibc's plain-C fallback bithack strlen which also has to get to an alignment boundary.

Comment: You don't need to `sub rsp, 8`; this is a leaf function so there are no function calls that would need a 16-byte-aligned RSP.  Also, you don't need to `push` anything: you don't use RBP for anything, and you could use call-clobbered RDX or R8 instead of call-preserved RBX.  Also, you should arrange your loop so a `jcc while_parallel` is at the bottom, instead of running an extra `jmp`.  This might mean undoing an `add rax, 8` after falling out of the loop.  Instead of `NOT rsi` / `cmp rsi, 0`, just do `cmp rsi, -1`.

Comment: Also, as discussed in comments on Soonts's answer on your last question, a 64-bit version of the `(((v) - 0x01010101UL) & ~(v) & 0x80808080UL)` bithack should be fewer operations, and still avoids any false-positives.  But it would need two constants, so startup overhead is somewhat worse for short strings.  Both would benefit from BMI1 for `andn`.  In this version, you could invert the constant for a copy-and-and instead of `mov`/`and`.

Comment: [parallel-processing] is about multi-threading, not SIMD / SWAR.  What you're doing is SWAR, a special case of SIMD.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAR .  It is taking advantage of data parallelism by doing multiple operations at once, but when people say "parallel processing", they mean something else.  That's why I retagged this and your previous question.